# How To Avoid Logic In Template?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to develop a forum application.

I'm trying to display the latest topic that's been posted in each category on a listing page. However, I realised after adding more than one category that I need a separate query for each single category or it just shows the newest topic overall.

I'm just not sure how to keep my logic in the view for the queries. Obviously, I could just perform the query inside of my for loop but that doesn't seem very MVT oriented.

Here's my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import ForumReply, ForumCategory, ForumTopic

def index(req):
    categories = ForumCategory.objects.all()

    #find latest topic or topic by reply
    topic = ForumTopic.objects.latest('created_at')
    reply = ForumReply.objects.latest('created_at')

    if (topic.created_at > reply.created_at):
        latest = topic
    else:
        latest = reply.topic

    return render(req, "forum/category_listing.html",
                  {'categories': categories, 'latest': latest})
```

And my category_listing.html:

```
{% extends '__base.html' %}
{% block content %}

    {% for category in categories %}
    <div class="forum_category">
        <h1><a href="{% url 'forum_topic_list' category.pk 1 %}">{{ category.title }}</a></h1>
        {{ category.body }}
        <br />
        <em>Latest Post: </em> {{ latest.title }} by {{ latest.user }} at {{ latest.created_at|date:"D d F Y h:i" }}
    </div>
    <br />
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Instead of worrying how to do this out of templates you should find a way to do the whole thing in **one** database query.

Comment: I'm very new to Django so a bit of help would be appreciated. Have hardly grazed the tip of its ORM

Comment: Personally I can't help as I haven't used Django in years. But the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/topics/db/queries/#related-objects) of course have a lot of info on the subject and a little bit of Googling will give you a load of tutorials and guides.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom template tag that returns the latest post for each category.

Something like this:

```
# views.py
def index(req):
    categories = ForumCategory.objects.all()
    return render(req, "forum/category_listing.html", {'categories': categories})

# templatetags/category_tags.py
@register.assignment_tag
def get_latest_post(category):
    # perform logic here for selecting latest post for specific category
    return latest


# category_listing.html
{% load category_tags %}
{% for category in categories %}
    {% get_latest_post category as latest %}
    <em>Latest Post: </em> {{ latest.title }} by {{ latest.user }} at {{ latest.created_at|date:"D d F Y h:i" }}
{% endfor %}
```

You can read the documentation for more information https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/#assignment-tags